# AssertionError: 401 != 200

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write a test case for a bug report and I keep getting the assertion error.

```
    list_url = ('/bugreport')

    def setUp(self):
        self.owner = User.objects.create_user(username="asdf122223", password = "asdf1222345")
        self.token = Token.objects.create(user=self.owner)
        self.owner.save()
        self.api_authentication()
    
    def api_authentication(self):
        self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIXATION='Token ' + self.token.key)
    
    def test_bug_report_authenticate(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.list_url, format="json")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def test_bug_report_un_authenticate(self):
        self.client.force_authenticate(user=None)
        response = self.client.get(self.list_url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

if anyone can tell me what im doign wrong, that would be huge, or point me in the right direction

Comment: What is `HTTP_AUTHORIXATION`?  Access control with kinky boots?  Shouldn't it be `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` ?

Comment: fixed the typo and still getting the same error